# trying to remove the ability to click a spot and jump to it on an <input type="range">

Tags: jquery, css, slider, uislider

I'm working on a little slider calculator and want to remove the ability for the user to click a point on the slider and have the slider jump to that point. In other words, I'd like to limit the interaction only to actually grabbing and moving the handle of the slider.

I've tried pushing the runnable-track off-screen with the old left: -999999px trick but it seems that the functionality i'm referring to is associated with the handle, not the track.

Any ideas?

http://codepen.io/Keganonymous/pen/zvygBz

```
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  margin-top: -70px;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  margin-top: 70px;
}
```

Comment: provide your code so we can do changes in it